# Show related inlines in the admin on form of model with GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-admin

I have simple models with generic relations from [this example at the Django Project](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline):

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")

class ImageLink(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

It's very simple to show inline *ImageLink* objects on the admin form of *Product*. It is demonstrated [in the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).

Can anyone suggest how have related *ImageLinks* inline on the admin form of an *Image* model?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** Updated example of model, becourse with previous, as Daniel sayd, it's not need to show objects inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neccessary use *generic.GenericTabularInline* for showing *ImageLink* objects inline on the *Product* form, as demonstrated in the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).

But if we need to show related *ImageLink* inline on the *Image* form, it can be done with simple child of *admin.TabularInline* class.

It's very simple solution. I think I'm stupid not to guess it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any related Products to show inline. Generic foreign keys, like normal ones, are one-to-many, with the 'one' side of the relation being the one containing the foreign key field. So in your case you still only have one Product for each Image, so there is no inline set to show.

Comment: You are absolutelly right. I have mistake in my example. And I know how to solve my issue now.